# Generate excel file using java with different column width

Tags: java, file-io, resultset, java-io

I am doing a java application (J2SE) which I have to generate a excel document (.xls). I did generate the file but I am not able to change the cell width dynamically according to the content which is having the maximum length in the same cell.

Here is my coding...

```
     try {

      ResultSet rs = com.dss.system.DBORCL.search("sql statement");

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

        rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Site");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Part No");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Part Description");
        int index = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {

            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) index);

            row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("site"));
            row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("part_no"));
            row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("description"));
            index++;
            }           


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("F:\\IFS\\IFSDOC" +    txtPLCode.getText() + "[" + currentDate + "-" + usesecond + "]" + ".xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Data is saved in excel file.");
        //  rs.close();
```

Comment: Have you not tried using setColumnWidth() ? http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setColumnWidth(int, int)

Comment: dude I just now tried this.No errors.But in my excel report when I use setColumnWidth((short) 1,(short) 10) that column not appeared.Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0) //for first column
sheet.autoSizeColumn(1) //for second column ... etc
```

Refer: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofit

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error in autoSizeColumn(0). I dont know why it is happening.